# Analysis of "The advantage of short paper titles"

Tags: p-value, kendall-tau

After seeing the paper, [The advantage of short paper titles](http://rsos.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/2/8/150266) showing a relationship between paper length rank and citation rank, I wondering what to make of the results. As a layman, my questions are:

**Is the result meaningful?** The p-value is tiny, but the tau values also seem pretty small (but largish N values make the p-value small).

**Why is it OK to include only the most highly cited papers?** What if many of the low-cited papers had short titles?

**What's the advantage of comparing ranks instead of actual values?** I imagine the ranks avoid outlier effects, but are super-long titles that common? I would think actual values would allow easier to understand models.

**The authors mention several known citation influencers (such as journal reputation and author reputation), but why do they only adjust for one of them (journal)?** Presumably it's because that's the only one they think is also correlated with title length rank.

*Sorry for multiple questions in one, but hopefully they form a coherent theme.*

Comment: This is basically an unconditional nonsense. There are so many endogeneity issues in their setup. For instance, what if the shorter titles reflect the broader applicability of the subject of the paper? So the longer titles would be more specific, making their potential audience narrower. It's just one consideration that comes to mind. I'm sure you can come up with a dozen others. It's garbage.